# How to generate datacenter and machine combinations depending on rules I have?

Tags: java, algorithm, combinations

I am working on a project in which I have three datacenter (as of now) and each datacenter will have some machines.

So I am storing the input in a `Map of String and List of String` as shown below.

```
Map<String, List<String>> datacenterMachineMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>();
```

Data in the above map can be like this. Below is one possible input combination and each datacenter won't have same machine, so two h1 is not possible in dc1 as an input-

```
{dc1=[h1, h2, h3]}
{dc2=[h1, h2, h3]}
{dc3=[h1, h2, h3]}
```

**ProblemStatement:-**

Basis on the above input, I need to return a mapping which will be `List<Map<String, String>>`, so for above input below mapping would be return as an output (this is one possible output combination which follows the below rules) -

```
[{dc1=h1, dc2=h2, dc3=h3}, 
{dc1=h2, dc2=h3, dc3=h1}, 
{dc1=h3, dc2=h1, dc3=h2}]
```

**Some Rules Are:-**

- In each row, datacenter should have alternate machines. If you see above, each row has alternate machine for each datacenter -  meaning `h1 for dc1`, `h2 for dc2`, `h3 for dc3` in first row.
- Secondly, I cannot have same machines in each row. So the below combination is not possible as it has same machines for two datacenter in one row `{dc1=h1, dc2=h1, dc3=h3}`.
- Thirdly, in the next row, I won't use those machines for the datacenter which have been used in the earlier rows. So second row cannot have `h1` for `dc1` as it was already used in first row by `dc1`.

Below are my input combinations -

```
List<String> hosts1 = Arrays.asList("h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "h6", "h7", "h8", "h9", "h10", "h11");
List<String> hosts2 = Arrays.asList("h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "h6", "h7", "h8", "h9", "h10", "h11");
List<String> hosts3 = Arrays.asList("h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "h6", "h7", "h8", "h9", "h10", "h11");

or

List<String> hosts1 = Arrays.asList("h2", "h1", "h3");
List<String> hosts2 = Arrays.asList("h2", "h1", "h3");
List<String> hosts3 = Arrays.asList("h2", "h1", "h3");

or

List<String> hosts1 = Arrays.asList("h1", "h2");
List<String> hosts2 = Arrays.asList();
List<String> hosts3 = Arrays.asList();

 Map<String, List<String>> maps = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>();
 maps.put("dc1", hosts1);
 maps.put("dc2", hosts2);
 maps.put("dc3", hosts3);

// output will go in mappings class
List<Map<String, String>> mappings = generateMappings(maps);
```

Below is my code which works fine on some of the input combinations but it doesn't works for other input combinations. I tried debugging but not able to understand what is causing this issue -

```
public static List<Map<String, String>> create(Map<String, List<String>> input) {
    List<Map<String, String>> output = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
    // find all datacenters
    List<String> datacenters = new ArrayList<String>(input.keySet());

    // find all machines
    Set<String> distinctMachines = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
    for (List<String> e : input.values()) {
        for (String machine : e) {
        if (!distinctMachines.contains(machine)) {
            distinctMachines.add(machine);
        }
        }
    }
    List<String> machines = new ArrayList<String>(distinctMachines);

    Set<String> generationHistory = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
    int machineIndex = 0; 
    int index = datacenters.size() > machines.size() ? datacenters.size() : machines.size(); 
    for(int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
        Map<String, String> row = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
        output.add(row);
        machineIndex = i;
        for(int j = 0; j < index; j++) {
        int datacenterIndex = j;
        if(datacenterIndex >= datacenters.size()) {
            datacenterIndex = 0;
        }
        String datacenter = datacenters.get(datacenterIndex);
        List<String> datacenterMachines = input.get(datacenter);
        if(machineIndex >= machines.size()) {
            machineIndex = 0;
        }
        String machine = machines.get(machineIndex++);
        // a combination is generated only if the actual
        // machines does exist in the actual datacenter 
        // and it has not already been generated i all previous rows
        if(datacenterMachines.contains(machine) && isNotYetGenerated(datacenter, machine, generationHistory)) {
            row.put(datacenter, machine);
        }
        }
    }

    return output;
}

private boolean isNotYetGenerated(String datacenter, String machine, 
                                  Set<String> generationHistory) {
    String key = datacenter + "=" + machine;
    boolean notYetGenerated = ! generationHistory.contains(key);
    if(notYetGenerated) {
        generationHistory.add(key);
    }
    return notYetGenerated;
}
```

Can anyone help me on this problem?

Comment: Any particular requirements concerning runnting time or so? What would be the output in the third example (where only `h1` and `h2` are available)?

Comment: @Marco13:I don't have as such requirements on the running time as of now. And It should be single list of two maps, and first map can have `dc1-h1` and second map will have `dc1-h2` or vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT** Completely updated based on the dicussion in the comments

My first approach was to recursively generate the combinations, and, during the recursion, maintain the information that was required to satisfy all constraints. The intention was to *only* create *valid* combinations in the first place. However, according to the comments, the assignment of machines to data centers is optional, and it is hard to detect the "valid" solutions with the recursive approach.

Thus, this new approach is slightly different (and much more pragmatic) : It computes all possible combinations of machines (including `null`), and checks each of these combinations whether it is "valid" - that is, contains each machine only once, and no data center has a machine that it already had before. If it is valid, it is stored in the result list, and the information about the machines that have been used is updated accordingly.

The potential drawback is that most of the combinations that are created here are invalid, because it computes the cartesian product of the machine sets. When the number of data centers / machines grows, this will become intractable. If this is a problem, then the computation of combinations will have to be pruned. This would not be so hard, for example, by skipping all combinations that start with `{ h1, h1 ... }` (because this already violates the rules), but would require some additional meditation about how to combine this with the other rules and still keep the implementation understandable.

I think that it would also be possible to find a simple and elegant solution with the recursive approach, but ... well... finding a simple solution often turns out to be hard...

(The `MixedRangeCombinationIterable` class is taken from https://github.com/javagl/Combinatorics/blob/master/src/main/java/de/javagl/utils/math/combinatorics/MixedRangeCombinationIterable.java and used here to compute the cartesian product of the machine sets)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.Set;


public class DatacenterMappingTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //        List<String> hosts1 = Arrays.asList("h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "h6", "h7", "h8", "h9", "h10", "h11");
        //        List<String> hosts2 = Arrays.asList("h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "h6", "h7", "h8", "h9", "h10", "h11");
        //        List<String> hosts3 = Arrays.asList("h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "h6", "h7", "h8", "h9", "h10", "h11");
        //
        //        or
        //        
        //        List<String> hosts1 = Arrays.asList("h1", "h2", "h3");
        //        List<String> hosts2 = Arrays.asList("h1", "h2", "h3");
        //        List<String> hosts3 = Arrays.asList("h1", "h2", "h3");
        //
        //        or
        //
        //        List<String> hosts1 = Arrays.asList("h1", "h2");
        //        List<String> hosts2 = Arrays.asList();
        //        List<String> hosts3 = Arrays.asList();

        List<String> hosts1 = Arrays.asList("h1", "h2", "h3"); 
        List<String> hosts2 = Arrays.asList("h1", "h2", "h3"); 
        List<String> hosts3 = Arrays.asList("h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5");        

        Map<String, List<String>> maps = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>();
        maps.put("dc1", hosts1);
        maps.put("dc2", hosts2);
        maps.put("dc3", hosts3);

        // output will go in mappings class
        List<Map<String, String>> mappings = generateMappings(maps);            

        for (Map<String, String> mapping : mappings)
        {
            System.out.println(mapping);
        }
    }

    public static List<Map<String, String>> generateMappings(Map<String, List<String>> input)
    {
        List<Map<String, String>> output = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        List<List<String>> inputValues = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
        for (List<String> inputValue : input.values())
        {
            List<String> extendedInputValue = new ArrayList<String>(inputValue);
            extendedInputValue.add(null);
            inputValues.add(extendedInputValue);
        }
        List<String> dataCenters = new ArrayList<String>(input.keySet());
        Map<String, Set<String>> usedMachinesForDataCenters =
            new LinkedHashMap<String, Set<String>>();
        MixedRangeCombinationIterable<String> iterable = 
            new MixedRangeCombinationIterable<String>(inputValues);        
        for (List<String> machines : iterable)
        {
            if (isValid(dataCenters, machines, usedMachinesForDataCenters))
            {
                Map<String, String> assignment = createMap(dataCenters, machines);
                output.add(assignment);
                store(dataCenters, machines, usedMachinesForDataCenters);
            }
        }
        return output;
    }

    private static Map<String, String> createMap(List<String> dataCenters, List<String> machines)
    {
        Map<String, String> result = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
        for (int i=0; i<machines.size(); i++)
        {
            String machine = machines.get(i);
            if (machine != null)
            {
                String dataCenter = dataCenters.get(i);
                result.put(dataCenter, machine);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static void store(List<String> dataCenters, List<String> machines, 
        Map<String, Set<String>> usedMachinesForDataCenters)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<machines.size(); i++)
        {
            String machine = machines.get(i);
            if (machine != null)
            {
                String dataCenter = dataCenters.get(i);
                Set<String> usedMachinesForDataCenter =
                    get(usedMachinesForDataCenters, dataCenter);
                usedMachinesForDataCenter.add(machine);
            }
        }
    }

    private static boolean isValid(List<String> dataCenters, List<String> machines, 
        Map<String, Set<String>> usedMachinesForDataCenters)
    {
        for (String machine : machines)
        {
            if (machine != null)
            {
                if (Collections.frequency(machines, machine) > 1)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i=0; i<machines.size(); i++)
        {
            String machine = machines.get(i);
            if (machine != null)
            {
                String dataCenter = dataCenters.get(i);
                Set<String> usedMachinesForDataCenter =
                    get(usedMachinesForDataCenters, dataCenter);
                if (usedMachinesForDataCenter.contains(machine))
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private static Set<String> get(Map<String, Set<String>> map, String key)
    {
        Set<String> result = map.get(key);
        if (result == null)
        {
            result = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
            map.put(key, result);
        }
        return result;
    }
}


/**
* A class providing an iterator over all combinations of a certain number
* of elements, where the valid ranges may be different for each element
* of the combination. For a set S = { S0, S1, ... Sn } there will be
* |S0| * |S1| * ... * |Sn| possible combinations. Example:<br />
* <pre>
* S0 = {A,B,C}, |S0| = 3
* S1 = {D,E} , |S1| = 2
* S2 = {A,E} , |S2| = 2
* S = { S0, S1, S2 }
* m = |S0| * |S1| * |S0| = 3 * 2 * 2 = 12 combinations
*
* Combinations:
* [A, D, A]
* [A, D, E]
* [A, E, A]
* [A, E, E]
* [B, D, A]
* [B, D, E]
* [B, E, A]
* [B, E, E]
* [C, D, A]
* [C, D, E]
* [C, E, A]
* [C, E, E]
* </pre>
*
* @param <T> The type of the elements
*/class MixedRangeCombinationIterable<T> implements Iterable<List<T>>
{
    /**
     * The input elements
     */
    private List<? extends Collection<? extends T>> sets;

    /**
     * The total number of elements that the iterator will provide
     */
    private final int numElements;

    /**
     * Creates an iterable over all combinations of one element
     * of each of the given sets.
     *
     * @param sets The input sets
     */
    public MixedRangeCombinationIterable(
        List<? extends Collection<? extends T>> sets)
    {
        this.sets = sets;
        int m = 0;
        if (sets.size() > 0)
        {
            m = 1;
        }
        for (Collection<? extends T> set : sets)
        {
            m *= set.size();
        }
        this.numElements = m;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<List<T>> iterator()
    {
        return new Iterator<List<T>>()
        {
            /**
             * The element counter
             */
            private int current = 0;

            /**
             * The current combination
             */
            private List<T> currentCombination = new ArrayList<T>();

            /**
             * The iterators over the individual sets
             */
            private List<Iterator<? extends T>> subIterators =
                new ArrayList<Iterator<? extends T>>(
                    Collections.<Iterator<? extends T>>nCopies(
                        sets.size(), null));

            // Initialize the sub-iterators and the first combination
            {
                if (numElements > 0)
                {
                    for (int i=0; i<sets.size(); i++)
                    {
                        Iterator<? extends T> subIterator =
                            sets.get(i).iterator();
                        subIterators.set(i, subIterator);
                        currentCombination.add(subIterator.next());
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public boolean hasNext()
            {
                return current < numElements;
            }

            @Override
            public List<T> next()
            {
                if (!hasNext())
                {
                    throw new NoSuchElementException("No more elements");
                }

                List<T> result = new ArrayList<T>(currentCombination);
                increase(sets.size()-1);
                current++;
                return result;
            }

            /**
             * Increases the selection of elements by one.
             *
             * @param index The index to increase
             */
            private void increase(int index)
            {
                if (index < 0)
                {
                    return;
                }
                Iterator<? extends T> subIterator = subIterators.get(index);
                if (subIterator.hasNext())
                {
                    currentCombination.set(index, subIterator.next());
                }
                else
                {
                    subIterator = sets.get(index).iterator();
                    subIterators.set(index, subIterator);
                    currentCombination.set(index, subIterator.next());
                    increase(index-1);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void remove()
            {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
                    "May not remove elements from a combination");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT2** The recursive variant again, capable of handling many machines, and obeying the rules that have been specified, but creating a different result than that of the example that was given...

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.Set;


public class DatacenterMappingTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Map<String, List<String>> maps = null;
        maps = createTestCase0();
        //maps = createTestCase(5, 500);

        // output will go in mappings class
        List<Map<String, String>> mappings = generateMappings(maps);

        for (Map<String, String> mapping : mappings)
        {
            System.out.println(mapping);
        }
    }

    private static Map<String, List<String>> createTestCase(int numDataCenters, int numMachines)
    {
        Map<String, List<String>> maps = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>();
        for (int i=0; i<numDataCenters; i++)
        {
            List<String> hosts = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int j=0; j<numMachines; j++)
            {
                hosts.add("h"+j);
            }
            maps.put("dc"+i, hosts);
        }
        return maps;
    }

    private static Map<String, List<String>> createTestCase0()
    {
        List<String> hosts1 = Arrays.asList("h1", "h2", "h3");
        List<String> hosts2 = Arrays.asList("h1", "h2", "h3");
        List<String> hosts3 = Arrays.asList("h1", "h2", "h3");
        Map<String, List<String>> maps = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>();
        maps.put("dc1", hosts1);
        maps.put("dc2", hosts2);
        maps.put("dc3", hosts3);
        return maps;
    }

    private static Map<String, List<String>> createTestCase1()
    {
        List<String> hosts1 = Arrays.asList("h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "h6", "h7", "h8", "h9", "h10", "h11");
        List<String> hosts2 = Arrays.asList("h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "h6", "h7", "h8", "h9", "h10", "h11");
        List<String> hosts3 = Arrays.asList("h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "h6", "h7", "h8", "h9", "h10", "h11");
        Map<String, List<String>> maps = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>();
        maps.put("dc1", hosts1);
        maps.put("dc2", hosts2);
        maps.put("dc3", hosts3);
        return maps;
    }

    private static Map<String, List<String>> createTestCase2()
    {
        List<String> hosts1 = Arrays.asList("h1", "h2");
        List<String> hosts2 = Arrays.asList();
        List<String> hosts3 = Arrays.asList();
        Map<String, List<String>> maps = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>();
        maps.put("dc1", hosts1);
        maps.put("dc2", hosts2);
        maps.put("dc3", hosts3);
        return maps;
    }

    private static Map<String, List<String>> createTestCase3()
    {
        List<String> hosts1 = Arrays.asList("h1", "h2", "h3"); 
        List<String> hosts2 = Arrays.asList("h1", "h2", "h3"); 
        List<String> hosts3 = Arrays.asList("h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5");        
        Map<String, List<String>> maps = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>();
        maps.put("dc1", hosts1);
        maps.put("dc2", hosts2);
        maps.put("dc3", hosts3);
        return maps;
    }




    public static List<Map<String, String>> generateMappings(
        Map<String, List<String>> input) 
    {
        List<Map<String, String>> output = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        List<String> dataCenters = new ArrayList<String>(input.keySet());

        Set<String> usedMachines = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
        Map<String, String> currentAssignment = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
        Map<String, Set<String>> usedMachinesForDataCenters =
            new LinkedHashMap<String, Set<String>>();

        while (true)
        {
            boolean generated = generateAssignments(
                input, dataCenters, 0, usedMachines, 
                usedMachinesForDataCenters, currentAssignment,
                output);
            if (!generated)
            {
                break;
            }
        };
        return output;
    }

    private static String indent(int n)
    {
        String s ="";
        for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            s += "  ";
        }
        return s;
    }

    private static boolean generateAssignments(
        Map<String, List<String>> input,
        List<String> dataCenters, 
        int dataCenterIndex,
         Set<String> usedMachines, 
        Map<String, Set<String>> usedMachinesForDataCenters,
        Map<String, String> currentAssignment,
        List<Map<String, String>> assignments)
    {
        //System.out.println(indent(dataCenterIndex)+"Computing assignment");

        if (dataCenterIndex >= dataCenters.size())
        {
            //System.out.println(indent(dataCenterIndex)+"Finished: "+currentAssignment);
            if (currentAssignment.size() == 0)
            {
                LinkedHashMap<String, String> assignment = 
                    new LinkedHashMap<String, String>(currentAssignment);
                assignments.add(assignment);
                return false;
            }

            for (String dataCenter : currentAssignment.keySet())
            {
                Set<String> usedMachinesForDataCenter = 
                    get(usedMachinesForDataCenters, dataCenter);
                usedMachinesForDataCenter.add(currentAssignment.get(dataCenter));
            }
            LinkedHashMap<String, String> assignment = 
                new LinkedHashMap<String, String>(currentAssignment);
            assignments.add(assignment);
            return true;
        }
        String dataCenter = dataCenters.get(dataCenterIndex);
        List<String> machinesForDataCenter = input.get(dataCenter);

        // Compute the machines that are available for the current data center.
        // That is, all machines except the ones that have already been used.
        List<String> availableMachinesForDataCenter = 
            new ArrayList<String>(machinesForDataCenter);
        Set<String> usedMachinesForDataCenter = 
            get(usedMachinesForDataCenters, dataCenter);
        availableMachinesForDataCenter.removeAll(usedMachines);
        availableMachinesForDataCenter.removeAll(usedMachinesForDataCenter);
        availableMachinesForDataCenter.add(null);

        //System.out.println(indent(dataCenterIndex)+"Assign any of "+availableMachinesForDataCenter+" to "+dataCenter);

        // Try to assign each of the available machines to the current
        // data center, and do the recursion
        for (String machine : availableMachinesForDataCenter)
        {
            //System.out.println(indent(dataCenterIndex)+"Assign "+machine+" to "+dataCenter);

            // Store the current mapping, and remember that the
            // machine was already used
            if (machine != null)
            {
                currentAssignment.put(dataCenter, machine);
                usedMachines.add(machine);
            }

            // Do the recursion
            boolean generated = generateAssignments(
                input, dataCenters, dataCenterIndex+1, usedMachines, 
                usedMachinesForDataCenters, currentAssignment,
                assignments);

            // Undo the assignment 
            currentAssignment.remove(dataCenter);
            usedMachines.remove(machine);

            if (generated)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }    


    private static <K, V> Set<V> get(Map<K, Set<V>> map, K key)
    {
        Set<V> set = map.get(key);
        if (set == null)
        {
            set = new LinkedHashSet<V>();
            map.put(key, set);
        }
        return set;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Marco.. I tried your example and it works on most of the use case.. It mostly fails on this input combination `List<String> hosts1 = Arrays.asList("h1", "h2", "h3");
  List<String> hosts2 = Arrays.asList("h1", "h2", "h3");
  List<String> hosts3 = Arrays.asList("h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5");` It only shows till h1, h2, h3 in all three datacenters, no h4 and h5 comes up. Can you see what's wrong if possible?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood some of the constraints: One assignment is `{dc1=h1, dc2=h2, dc3=h3}`, the other is `{dc1=h2, dc2=h1, dc3=h4}`, the third one might start with `{dc1=h3...`, but there is no machine left that could be assigned to `dc2`. So what should be the result in this case? However, I'll add some debugging output....

Comment: One possible output combination is like this for the above input as I mentioned in my comment `{dc1=h1, dc2=h2, dc3=h3}
{dc1=h2, dc2=h3, dc3=h4}
{dc1=h3, dc3=h5}
{dc3=h1}
{dc2=h1, dc3=h2}`

Comment: We need to use all the inputs for particular datacenter just making sure it follows the rules I have.. It's not mandatory to have all the datacenters in each Map, if it is not following the rule, then we won't put them up in that map.

Comment: Any thoughts how this can be achieved?

Comment: @SSH Changed the code to use another approach, and added an explaination that indicates why I first asked whether there are requirements concerning the running time ;-) (Even the "large" example that you posted works in "no time", and even when the number of data centers is higher, but ... I'm not sure how it would cope with 100 data centers and 1000 machines or so...)

Comment: Number of datacenters won't be greater than 4 or 5 for sure.. But number of machines can be max 500.. that's all.. let me try your new approach then.. thanks for the help.

Comment: @SSH OK, for 500 machines this will not be feasible, because the cartesian product becomes far too large. I thought about the problem again, and once more tried the recursive approach, but am pretty sure that the problem is underspecified. For example, a solution for the first (main) example in your question could also be `{dc1=h1, dc2=h2, dc3=h3}, {dc1=h2, dc2=h1}, {dc1=h3, dc3=h1}, {dc2=h3, dc3=h2}`. It obeys the rules, as far as I can see. However, I'll add another EDIT with the recursive variant that creates this mapping, and even works for 500 machines